Flinksql read iceberg using AWS Glue cross account
I'd like to learn more about the nuances of reading iceberg tables using AWS Glue in cross account and appreciate your feeback.
AWS Account#producer:
Producing iceberg tables using AWS Glue catalog on s3 in parquet format. Lets say participant_stream table on s3 location: s3://mybucket/warehouse
where databasename:mydb
AWS Account#consumer:
FlinkSQL job reads from iceberg table
CREATE CATALOG  `mycatalog`
WITH (
    'type'='iceberg',
    'catalog-impl'='org.apache.iceberg.aws.glue.GlueCatalog',
    'io-impl'='org.apache.iceberg.aws.s3.S3FileIO',
    'warehouse'='s3://mybucket/warehouse'
);

USE CATALOG `mycatalog`;

CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW default_catalog.default_database.participant_distinct AS
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY
                 uuid
                 ORDER BY `timestamp`,`offset` desc) AS rownum
      FROM mycatalog.mydb.participants_stream /*+  OPTIONS('streaming'='true', 'monitor-interval'='15s') */)
WHERE rownum = 1;

Question#1: Is this mycatalog a temporary flink pointer to the location where catalog is ?? Since i have cross account setup i have read Only access.
Question#2: Does my consumer account need read only access to s3 and AWS Glue?
Question#3: Can i directly access the table name with database prefix after the use catalog or do i have to access it like mycatalog.mydb.participants_stream ?
